# How to manually delay Anacron for a few hours?

Tags: cron, anacron

I have Ubuntu running on an older laptop.  I have noticed that maintenance cron jobs slow things for a few minutes when they execute.  This is a problem if, for example, I need the resources for a video call.

The cron jobs are controlled by anacron. Is there a command that I can issue from the terminal that would delay all such jobs from executing for say, 3 hours, while I get on with more important things?